# How to print a specific string after you split the line from text file (closed)

Tags: c#, text-files

I've got a task to split a string, then print a specific string.

For example:

```
string str = "Hello@world@,@morning!"
```

I split between "@" and I want to print the word "Hello".

```
string[] textsplit;
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    textsplit = lines[i].Split('@');
    foreach (String s in textsplit)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s[0].ToString());
    } 
}
```

When I try to run the program , instead of printing the word "Hello", it prints "H" only .

Can someone help to fix it?

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: It's printing the first character because that's the code you wrote. If you want the whole string, then pass the whole string to the `Show()` method, i.e. `s`

Comment: `s[0]` is just the first character of the string `s`.  Try `MessageBox.Show(s)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I already got the answer

Instead of using `foreach`, I should use `for`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    textsplit = lines[i].Split('@');
    for (int j = 0; j < textsplit.Length; j++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(textsplit[0]);
        break;
    }
}
```

and it works!

Edit: so it won't need any `for`/`foreach` statements.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    textsplit = lines[i].Split('@');
    MessageBox.Show(textsplit[0]);
}
```

Just do this, and it will be fine.

Thanks PeterDuniho for the help!

Comment: That seems like a silly way to display just one string from the array. Why have the loop at all, if you're just going to break out after the first iteration?

Comment: @PeterDuniho hmm i dont know the good way to print the solution , because i only want to print the word hello , and with the foreach seems like it's impossible to do so , i try with the for statement.

Comment: _"with the foreach seems like it's impossible to do so"_ -- it would work fine with `foreach` as well, if you'd only written the code correctly. But the main issue here is: **you don't need a loop at all**. Why try to do it with either `foreach` or `for`, when neither is required, nor adds anything useful?

Comment: @PeterDuniho oh yea , ur right , i try to messagebox.show(textsplit[0]) without the  foreach and it works , hehe sry , i must explore it further before i ask this question ..

Comment: @PeterDuniho but thanks for the advice, without it , i never think about that .. appreciate that sir

Answer (score 0):

you should change

```
MessageBox.Show(s[0]);
```

to

```
MessageBox.Show(s);
```

the reason is that after you split, each element in textsplit is a string that contains a complete word as you expected. However, you print s[0] - the first character of the word, so only the 'h' was print out.